# How to write a mysql where query with userinput (XML filter with PHP)

Tags: php, xml

I need some assistance. I am trying to filter a specific row from sql into XML file

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE 1";
```

If I use this it shows all the rows from the SQL database, what i want to do is only show a line that equals a query from a form

The form code is as follow

```
<a href="phpsqlajax_genxml3.php?msisdn=<? echo $rows['msisdn']; ?>" class="update">
```

If i use the following:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE msisdn='$msisdn'";
```

The URL shows the query but it is not filtering just that line it then shows no data in the XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to read the value from the URL (the GET variable) into the PHP variable:

```
 $msisdn = $_GET['msisdn'];
```

Then, validate that before you put it into your query (e.g. with [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)).

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to use the `$_GET` superglobal array :

```
$msisdn = $_GET['msisdn'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE msisdn='$msisdn'";
```

on modern PHP hosts URL arguments are not automatically cast into variables (it is a security issue).

Comment: Please don't advise to use `$_GET` directly in a query.

Comment: fixed, even though I would assume that most people here looks for what is wrong with their code, not lessons in security (that's a whole other topic, and simply escaping url arguments won't save them). Fixed the answer though :)

Comment: Your "fix" is just as bad, if not worse. The point is to validate it, not put it in another variable. Even though you cannot completely fix their security holes, advising something that is blatantly wrong isn't the way either.

Comment: it is not the scope of the question to make the code secure. it is to assist them in making it work. Securing the code is different. This is not a site about educating developers, it's about helping them solve problems. My answer solves the problem.

Comment: So does enabling `register_globals`.

Comment: Using $_GET works and filters the XML file but now it is not showing the markers on google maps. Will try and puzzle out what went wrong there thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query="SELECT TOP 1 * FROM lbs_ WHERE msisdn='$msisdn'";
```

You probably also want to include some sort of sort order to the end.

Comment: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 * FROM lbs_ WHERE msisdn=''' at line 1

Error i Get with that code

Comment: Sorry, assumed MS SQL, MYSQL would be  "SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE msisdn='$msisdn' LIMIT 1"